# how to assign values from a file line in to a map in Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to write a self of key value pairs, later be used as a rule engine. Here what i am trying to achieve is getting the following code to make a map called "f" and assign the values on the file line to it. However the following code throws an exception saying  "f is not a type"

Is the method im doing to achieve the above task is correct? if not please suggest a better way of doing it, and better if you can provide me with a sample code
How to assign the line value to the map? better if you can provide me with a sample code

Thank you in advance

**rules file**

```
"name": "hero", "age":"27
"name": "villein", "age":"30
```

**code**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("rules")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        var f = make(map[string]string)
        f {scanner.Text()}
        fmt.Println(f)
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to find or write a parser for the rules file format.  Is the file a well known format?

Comment: its on linux im doing this, so actually the file is just a text file. i tried with this on csv format. but then there is issues with the double quotations.

Comment: It sounds like you might have control over the format of the text file.  Can you use JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [JSON](https://www.json.org/) for the file format so you can the JSON parser in the standard library:

```
[
{"name": "hero", "age":"27"},
{"name": "villein", "age":"30"}
]
```

With this format, the code is:

```
file, err := os.Open("rules")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()
var data []map[string]string
if err := json.NewDecoder(file).Decode(&data); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// variable data is a slice of maps
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QU-UUsZ2geb)

Comment: Hey @ThunderCat this looks amazing, let me check this and get back to you soon as possible

Comment: Can we wrtie `defer file.Close()` before `err` check?

Comment: @overexchange it doesn't makes much sense to close if we didn't succeed in opening the file, so you can but it's wrong.